# 3N linear Equations

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra

Given the following equation:

[image: sum on j (Aij * Xj)=bi i,j=1:N]

It will be 3N linear equations.

Each `Aij` is a 3x3 matrix. `Xj` s are 3x1 unknowns. And `bi` s are known 3x1 matrix.

How can I Combine 3x3 matrix to build a 3Nx3N matrix?
I'm trying to find a method to work out this question.

Comment: oh my god that's the biggest LaTeX I've ever seen! Run away before it attacks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have created all of your matrices `Aij` and vectors `bi` as variables in MATLAB, you can put them all into one large system of equations `AX = b` by simple [concatenation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/math/f1-84864.html) using square brackets and semicolons. For example, when `N = 3`, you can do the following:

```
A = [A11 A12 A13; A21 A22 A23; A31 A32 A33];  %# A 9-by-9 matrix
b = [b1; b2; b3];                             %# A 9-by-1 vector
```

Then, once you solve your system of equations (using `X = A\b;` or some other method), you can break `X` up into its individual 3-by-1 parts. For the above example of `N = 3`, you can do the following:

```
X1 = X(1:3);
X2 = X(4:6);
X3 = X(7:9);
```

Comment: Problem is that  main matrix is not block diagonal. Please look at this     http://up.iranblog.com/images/dsc0s5plfga1vpwirtyn.png      B is a constant

Comment: @user601908: Did you mean for this comment to be on 3lectrologos' answer?

Comment: Ok  can  you guide me Here . I'm looking for a way to concatenation them when N is large.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897989/concatenation-of-n2-3x3-matrixes-into-a-3nx3n-matrix