# How to rejoin a split image in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have split a large image into smaller blocks, since the time taken for processing the image as a whole is quite a lot in MATLAB. Now after I have split the images and done the processing which I need, I need to rejoin the image from those blocks. How do I do it?

This is how i am splitting the image:

```
k=1;
    for i=1:floor(nCol/6):(5*nCol/6)
        for j=1:floor(nRow/6):(5*nRow/6)

            im{k}=I(i:floor(i+nCol/6),j:floor(j+nRow/6),1:3);
            k=k+1;

        end

    end


for i=1:k-1
      part=some_function(im{i});
```

now this part is an array of images itself..that is to access it i use

```
for i=1:length(part)
         figure; imshow(part{1}{i});
```

basically this part contains parts of the block which has been processed and is split into many parts. So basically first i need to combine part into one image and combine all parts into one whole image. I hope you understood what i mean.

Comment: You might find this question useful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6283918/97160

Comment: It's hard to tell you how to rejoin the images when you haven't explained *how* you split them in the first place. You should post the code you use to split them.

Comment: Why split them into cell arrays? Maybe you could use blkproc of blockproc instead.

Answer (score 0):

Usually images in MATLAB are just matrices.  So you can glue them back together with the usual horizontal and vertical concatenation commands:

```
WholeImage = [ NorthWest NorthEast; ...
               SouthWest SouthEast ];
```

Assuming your image was broken up into four pieces, this will put them back together.

If you had a broken it up into a variable number of pieces and stored the pieces in a cell array, then `cell2mat` should be helpful in gluing the pieces back together.

Answer (score 0):

If you have splitted the image into channels (eg. RGB), then you may use [cat command](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cat.html) as follows:

```
img = cat(3,R,G,B);
```