# Is there a substitute for blockproc in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix

I've been using [`blockproc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/blockproc.html) for processing images blockwise. Unfortunately, `blockproc` is part of the Image Processing Toolbox, which I don't have on my personal computer.

Is there a combination of functions in base Matlab that can substitute for `blockproc`?

---

My initial guess was to use `im2col` to transform each block into columns, and then `arrayfun` to process each column. Then I realized that `im2col` is also a part of the Image Processing Toolbox, so that doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: related question: [Matlab - merge submatrices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6283918/matlab-merge-submatrices)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is an example using MAT2CELL. It dividing the image into N-by-M tiles, and handles the case when the image size is not evenly divisible by the number of tiles.

```
%# 2D grayscale image
I = imread('coins.png');

%# desird number of horizontal/vertical tiles to divide the image into
numBlkH = 4;
numBlkW = 4;

%# compute size of each tile in pixels
[imgH,imgW,~] = size(I);
szBlkH = [repmat(fix(imgH/numBlkH),1,numBlkH-1) imgH-fix(imgH/numBlkH)*(numBlkH-1)];
szBlkW = [repmat(fix(imgW/numBlkW),1,numBlkW-1) imgW-fix(imgW/numBlkW)*(numBlkW-1)];

%# divide into tiles, and linearize using a row-major order
C = mat2cell(I, szBlkH, szBlkW)';
C = C(:);

%# display tiles i subplots
figure, imshow(I)
figure
for i=1:numBlkH*numBlkW
    subplot(numBlkH,numBlkW,i), imshow( C{i} )
end
```

The input image and the resulting tiles:

[image: input_image]
[image: tiles]

Answer (score 2):

Won't [mat2tiles](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35085-split-nd-array-into-equal-sized-cells) together with `cellfun` and `cell2mat` do more or less what `blockproc` does?

You could write a wrapper yourself to make it use the same arguments as `blockproc`, I don't think it should be that hard to do.