# Does the segmentation of the image into blocks depend on the size of that image?

Tags: image, image-processing, matlab, image-segmentation

I asked two days ago about how to segment image into blocks in [how to segment the image into block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109360/segment-the-image-into-blocks). And fortunately I have got the best answer by Dear chappjc.

```
[m,n] = size(Image);
numBlocksX = 10; numBlocksY = 10;
bsX = ceil(n/numBlocksX); bsY = ceil(m/numBlocksY);
numFullBlocksX = floor(n/bsX); numFullBlocksY = floor(m/bsY);
xBlocks = [repmat(bsX,numFullBlocksX,1); mod(n,bsX)*ones(mod(n,bsX)>0)];
yBlocks = [repmat(bsY,numFullBlocksY,1); mod(m,bsY)*ones(mod(m,bsY)>0)];
blockCell = mat2cell(Image,yBlocks,xBlocks);
```

**My problem:**

My image has the size 160 x 160.
The code works well when I try to segment the image into 8 x 8 number of blocks, or 10 x 10, or 12 x 12, ... etc.

But when I try to segment the image into 22 x 22 number of blocks, the code works but the image is being segmented into 21 x 21 instead of 22 x 22!!

Does the segmentation depend on the size of the original image? Because when I work with an image that is larger, the image being segmented into 22 x 22.

I need only your opinions about my problem (If the segmentation depends on the size of the image?)

Please i need your help!

Comment: Have you tried going through the code line by line to see whether you understand what it does?

Comment: Sincerely no, i didn't understand all the lines, but it works well :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a sense, yes, the segmentation will depend on the original image's size because it might happen that either/both the size of X and Y dimensions of your original image are not perfectly divisible by MxN (the total number of blocks you would like to have in the end).

How do you want to treat the case where mod(n,bsX) or mod(m,bsY) are non-zero? Are you OK with having some of the border blocks be different sizes than the rest? If no, then you must change the image size such that the size of each dimension is perfectly divisible (modulo = 0) by the number of blocks.

```
[m,n] = size(image);
numBlocksY = 13; numBlocksX = 11;
resized = imresize(image, [ (numBlocksY*ceil(m/numBlocksY) ), (numBlocksX*ceil(n/numBlocksY)) ]);
[o,p] = size(resized)
mod(o,numBlocksY)
mod(p,numBlocksX)
```

You will find that the mod results in zero. The resized image now has sizes that are perfectly divisible by the number of divisions (blocks) you want in each dimension. All you have left to do is call mat2cell on the resized image with the correct parameters - but I will leave this to you. This way you will still have MxN blocks, but they will all be the same size. Where the size is calculated as:

```
blockXsize = o/numBlocksY;
blockYsize = p/numBlocksX;
```

You need to use these sizes in some way to correctly call mat2cell.

Comment: thank you for your answer! :) ,, désolé it is "into" not "int", it's a wrong from my keyboard.. So does a way to modify the code in order to have the possibility to segment the image into more larger number of blocks ?

Comment: Yes, of course. But it depends on the final result you wish to achieve. Does each block have to be the same size? I would assume so. In this case you must resize the image first. Then everything else is much easier.

Comment: do you mean that i must resize my original image in order to get an image more larger and which can be segmented into more larger number of blocks ?

Comment: That's right.  @Christinia How would you like a 160 width image divided into 22 horizontal blocks? For example, write out how many pixels you would like in each block. The code works better the other way, going from block size to number of blocks.

Comment: But i tried to segment this image into 14 x 14 for example, and i got a good result.. from 1 to 21 x 21 , the code works well,, but from 22x22 and +,, i got a problem (the problem is that the image being segmented into 21x21 instead of 22x22)

Comment: @Christina I mean, what would you like to have in the result for 22 blocks from 160 pixels? What would be the size of each cell? There's no way to end up with either 22 equal size blocks OR 21 equal size blocks plus 1 smaller block, so there is a limited application of this approach, sorry. However, it could be modified to have one larger block at the end...

Comment: Do you mean that after the segmentation, the block size must contain an integer number of pixels ? it can't contain a real number of pixels (16.3 for example) ? that is why i got a problem with 22x22 ?

Comment: Of course not. Pixels are not continuous like real numbers. You must have an integer number of pixels in any image/block.