# I want to write a matlab code that divides an image into subimages 10x10 (original image is 100x100)

Tags: matlab

```
S=imread(img2.gif); 
for img=1:100;
   C = mat2cell(S,[10 10],[10 10]);
   plot(C);
end
```

Comment: If your image is not colormap-based, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20336288/for-loop-to-split-matrix-to-equal-sized-sub-matrices

Comment: so? do you want to ask something in particular? `mat2cell` is a good start - maybe you should read its documentation. The remainder of your code looks pretty confused...

Comment: S=imread('img1.gif');

[x,y] = size(S);

for i = 1:20:x
  for j = 1:20:y
    tmp = S(i:(i+19), j:(j+19));
    % Do something interesting with "tmp" here.
  end
end
      figure
      colormap((gray));
      imagesc(tmp);
      
      this code is perfect but with a 10x10 not fuction.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will separate the image into sub images of a specified size.

```
im = imread('peppers.png');
widthSub = 10;
heightSub = 10;
numHeightFull = floor(size(im,1)/heightSub);
numWidthFull = floor(size(im,2)/widthSub);
if mod(size(im,1),heightSub) == 0
    heights = heightSub*ones(1,numHeightFull);
else
    heights = [heightSub*ones(1,numHeightFull),mod(size(im,1),heightSub)];
end
if mod(size(im,2),widthSub) == 0
    widths = widthSub*ones(1,numWidthFull);
else
    widths = [widthSub*ones(1,numWidthFull),mod(size(im,2),widthSub)];
end
if ndims(im) < 2 
    subImages = mat2cell(im,heights,widths);
elseif ndims(im) > 2
    subImages = mat2cell(im,heights,widths,size(im,3));
end
```