# bsxfun-like for matrix product

Tags: matlab, matrix-multiplication, bsxfun

I need to multiply a matrix `A` with n matrices, and get `n` matrices back. For example, multiply a 2x2 matrix with 3 2x2 matrices stacked as a 2x2x3 Matlab array. `bsxfun` is what I usually use for such situations, but it only applies for element-wise operations. 
I could do something like:

```
blkdiag(a, a, a) * blkdiag(b(:,:,1), b(:,:,2), b(:,:,3))
```

but I need a solution for arbitrary `n` - ?

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/311944 check out the comments for FEX links

Comment: Cannot test now, but in the example `times` is used, perhaps `mtimes` can be substituted here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can `reshape` the stacked matrices. Suppose you have `k`-by-`k` matrix `a` and a stack of `m` `k`-by-`k` matrices `sb` and you want the product `a*sb(:,:,ii)` for `ii = 1..m`. Then all you need is

```
sza = size(a);
b = reshape( b, sza(2), [] ); % concatenate all matrices aloong the second dim
res = a * b; 
res = reshape( res, sza(1), [], size(sb,3) ); % stack back to 3d
```

Comment: +1 Well thought. But you need to store `size(sb,3)` before reshaping `b`, in order to use it at the end

Comment: @LuisMendo if you pay close attention I have two variables: `sb` for the "stacked" version and just `b` for the resized one.

Comment: Oh I see. I thought you were using (and overwriting) `b`.

Comment: @LuisMendo but you are right that when reshaping and messing with arrays' sizes one better keep track of what is going on...

Comment: @Shai In this case it should be `b = reshape( sb, sza(2), [] );`

Comment: BTW, what if I'd like to calculate `sb(:,:,ii)*a`?

Answer (score 3):

Your solution can be adapted to arbitrary size using [comma-saparated lists](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html?s_tid=doc_12b) obtained from cell arrays:

```
[k m n] = size(B);
Acell = mat2cell(repmat(A,[1 1 n]),k,m,ones(1,n));
Bcell = mat2cell(B,k,m,ones(1,n));
blkdiag(Acell{:}) * blkdiag(Bcell{:});
```

You could then stack the blocks on a 3D array using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20337173/2586922), and keep only the relevant ones.

But in this case a good old loop is probably faster:

```
C = NaN(size(B));
for nn = 1:n
    C(:,:,nn) = A * B(:,:,nn);
end
```

Answer (score 1):

For large stacks of matrices and/or vectors over which to execute matrix multiplication, speed can start becoming an issue. To avoid re-inventing the wheel, you could simply compile and use the following fast MEX code:
[MTIMESX - Mathworks](https://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25977-mtimesx-fast-matrix-multiply-with-multi-dimensional-support).
As a rule of thumb, MATLAB is often quite inefficient at executing for loops over large numbers of operations which look like they should be vectorizable; I cannot think of a straightforward way of generalising Shai's answer to this case.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Given that the link itself is to the mathworks page for downloading code developed by a 3rd party ( [mtimesx - GitHub](https://github.com/cybertk/mtimesx) ), it would not be appropriate for me to claim any part of their work as my own answer. If the link becomes broken, I would naturally attempt to replace it or else delete my answer.