# divide a picture in blocks of size (10-by-20) in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a black and white image .  The image is of 280x420 pixels, and each pixel is a value within the interval [0,1]. I want to divide the picture in blocks of size (10-by-20), this will give 28x21 (= 588) blocks. 
((In order to create the input vectors, each block should be written
as (200-by-1) vectors, where each column of the blocks has been added
to the previous one. In this way we will have 588 input vectors of size
200.))
How to do that and what code should I use??
thanks

Comment: http://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2col.html

Comment: I think you are looking for `im2col` from `Image Processing Toolbox`. If you don't have it, use [`Efficient Implementation of im2col` and `col2im`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25449279/efficient-implementation-of-im2col-and-col2im).

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20337173/2586922) what you want?

Comment: thank you ,, so the code is like this : `A = reshape(linspace(0,1,16),[4 4])'; 
B = im2col(A,[2 2]);
M = mean(B);
newA = col2im(M,[1 1],[3 3])`                                                                  Am I using right numbers???