# Rearrange sliding blocks into columns for a 3D array (IM2COL in 3D) - MATLAB

Tags: performance, matlab, multidimensional-array, vectorization

Given a matrix **A**(*mxnxc*) (*c* can be arbitrary), I want to sample patches(*pxp*) in sliding window scheme with stepsize *d*, and rearrange all the *pxpxc* patches into vectors. 
I can do it within nested for-loops, but it is very time consuming. How to do this quickly?

Comment: So, the output would be `2D` with `number of rows = p*p*c`, right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.@Divakar

Comment: I see. So, `im2col_3D_sliding_v2` from the posted solution below would work hopefully. I would keep the other version, future readers might be benefited from it.

Comment: Yes, *im2col_3D_sliding_v2* is a good solution. Your effort is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can extend [`this solution to Efficient Implementation of im2col and col2im`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25454746/3293881) again with [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) for a 3D array case to solve your case.

Now, there are two possible interpretations to the question :

- Extract blocks of size `p x p` and as vectors each, do this for entire first `2D` slice and then repeat this for all slices in `3D`, resulting in a `3D` output.
- Gather blocks of size `p x p x c` as vectors each and do this in a sliding manner across the entire array, resulting in a `2D` output.

These two interpretations are implemented as `im2col_3D_sliding_v1` and `im2col_3D_sliding_v2` respectively and listed next.

**im2col_3D_sliding_v1 :**

```
function out = im2col_3D_sliding_v1(A,blocksize,stepsize)

%// Store blocksizes
nrows = blocksize(1);
ncols = blocksize(2);

%// Store stepsizes along rows and cols
d_row = stepsize(1);
d_col = stepsize(2);

%// Get sizes for later usages
[m,n,r] = size(A);

%// Start indices for each block
start_ind = reshape(bsxfun(@plus,[1:d_row:m-nrows+1]',[0:d_col:n-ncols]*m),[],1); %//'

%// Row indices
lin_row = permute(bsxfun(@plus,start_ind,[0:nrows-1])',[1 3 2]);  %//'

%// 2D linear indices
lidx_2D = reshape(bsxfun(@plus,lin_row,[0:ncols-1]*m),nrows*ncols,[]);

%// 3D linear indices
lidx_3D = bsxfun(@plus,lidx_2D,m*n*permute((0:r-1),[1 3 2]));

%// Get linear indices based on row and col indices and get desired output
out = A(lidx_3D);

return;
```

**im2col_3D_sliding_v2 :**

```
function out = im2col_3D_sliding_v2(A,blocksize,stepsize)

%// Store blocksizes
nrows = blocksize(1);
ncols = blocksize(2);

%// Store stepsizes along rows and cols
d_row = stepsize(1);
d_col = stepsize(2);

%// Get sizes for later usages
[m,n,r] = size(A);

%// Start indices for each block
start_ind = reshape(bsxfun(@plus,[1:d_row:m-nrows+1]',[0:d_col:n-ncols]*m),[],1); %//'

%// Row indices
lin_row = permute(bsxfun(@plus,start_ind,[0:nrows-1])',[1 3 2]);  %//'

%// 2D linear indices
lidx_2D = reshape(bsxfun(@plus,lin_row,[0:ncols-1]*m),nrows*ncols,[]);

%// 3D linear indices
lidx_3D = bsxfun(@plus,permute(lidx_2D,[1 3 2]),m*n*(0:r-1));

%// Final 2D linear indices
lidx_2D_final = reshape(lidx_3D,[],size(lidx_2D,2));

%// Get linear indices based on row and col indices and get desired output
out = A(lidx_2D_final);

return;
```

**Sample runs**

(I) Input array :

```
>> A
A(:,:,1) =
    23   109    63     1    37   153
   110    31   201    57    69   230
    66   127    19     1    45   240
    76   181   101    49    36    57
A(:,:,2) =
   124    18   244     2   141    95
    96   112   110   174    56   228
   134    45   246   181   197   219
    68     7   195   165    59   103
```

(II) Input parameters :

```
>> blocksize = [2,3]; %// blocksize along rows, cols
>> stepsize = [2,2];  %// stepsize along rows, cols
```

(III) Outputs with two versions :

```
>> im2col_3D_sliding_v1(A,blocksize,stepsize)
ans(:,:,1) =
    23    66    63    19
   110    76   201   101
   109   127     1     1
    31   181    57    49
    63    19    37    45
   201   101    69    36
ans(:,:,2) =
   124   134   244   246
    96    68   110   195
    18    45     2   181
   112     7   174   165
   244   246   141   197
   110   195    56    59

   >> im2col_3D_sliding_v2(A,blocksize,stepsize)
ans =
    23    66    63    19
   110    76   201   101
   109   127     1     1
    31   181    57    49
    63    19    37    45
   201   101    69    36
   124   134   244   246
    96    68   110   195
    18    45     2   181
   112     7   174   165
   244   246   141   197
   110   195    56    59
```

Comment: Isn't it supposed to have a parameterised stepsize `d` as well?

Comment: @kkuilla Yeah, I was sort of waiting for output size clarification from OP to incorporate stepsize. Just added that as param in the edits :)

Comment: Good solution. Thanks.

Comment: Can the process be reversed according? That is accumulate the patches at the sampled location and then divided by the accumulated times to get a probability output?

Comment: @LiangXiao I think it would make sense to post that as a separate question.