# Create a neighbourhood graph from a given binary matrix using matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, adjacency-matrix

I am trying to create a neighbourhood graph from a given binary matrix `B`.  Neighbourhood graph (`A`) is defined as an adjacency matrix such that

```
(A(i,j) = A(j,i) = 1)
```

if the original matrix `B(i) = B(j) = 1` and `i` and `j` are adjacent to each (left, right, up, down or diagonal). Here I used the linear subscript to access the original matrix `B`. For example, consider the below matrix

```
B = [ 0 1 0; 
      0 1 1; 
      0 0 0 ];
```

My `A` will be a 9 * 9 graph as given below

```
A = [ 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0; 
      0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0; 
      0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0; 
      0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0; 
      0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0; 
      0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0; 
      0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0; 
      0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0; 
      0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ];
```

Since in the original `B` matrix, `B(4)`, `B(5)` and `B(8)` are adjacent with corresponding entries `1`, the adjacency matrix `A` has `1` at `A(4,5)`, `A(5,4)`, `A(4,8)`, `A(8,4)`, `A(5,8)` and `A(8,5)`.

How can I create such an adjacency matrix `A` given the matrix `B` in an efficient way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't require any toolbox, and works for square or rectangular matrices. It uses array operations with complex numbers.

Consider a binary matrix `B` of size `M`×`N`.

1. Create an `M`×`N` matrix, `t`, that contains the complex coordinates of each nonzero entry of `B`. That is, entry `t(r,c)` contains `r+1j*c` if `B(r,c)` is nonzero, and `NaN` otherwise.
2. Compute an `M*N`×`M*N` matrix, `d`, containing the absolute difference for each pair of entries of `B`. Pairs of entries of `B` that are nonzero and adjacent will produce `1` or `sqrt(2)` in matrix `d`.
3. Build the result matrix, `A`, such that it contains `1` iff the corresponding entry in `d` equals `1` or `sqrt(2)`. Equivalently, and more robust to numerical errors, iff the corresponding entry in `d` is between `0` and `1.5`.

Code:

```
B = [0 1 0; 0 1 1; 0 0 0]; % input
t = bsxfun(@times, B, (1:size(B,1)).') + bsxfun(@times, B, 1j*(1:size(B,2)));
t(t==0) = NaN; % step 1
d = abs(bsxfun(@minus, t(:), t(:).')); % step 2
A = d>0 & d<1.5; % step 3
```

To get `B` back from `A`:

```
B2 = zeros(sqrt(size(A,1)));
B2(any(A,1)) = 1;
```

Comment: I ended up using your solution as the other one gave an error when dealt with binary images.  Is it possible to get the B back from A

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using image processing toolbox* that creates  sparse matrix representation of the adjacency matrix:

```
B = [ 0 1 0; 
      0 1 1; 
      0 0 0 ]

n = numel(B);
C = zeros(size(B));
f = find(B);
C(f) = f;

D = padarray(C,[1 1]);
%If you don't have image processing toolbox
%D = zeros(size(C)+2);
%D(2:end-1,2:end-1)=C;
E = bsxfun(@times, im2col(D,[3 3]) , reshape(B, 1,[]));
[~ ,y] = find(E);
result = sparse(nonzeros(E),y,1,n,n);
result(1:n+1:end) = 0;
```

*More efficient implementation of `im2col` can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25454746/6579744).

Comment: for a different sized matrix (not necessarily square), I can simply change to im2col(D,size(B)) should work right ?

Comment: No you should use `[3 3]` because it shows adjacency of each matrix element.

Comment: given the "result" matrix, how can I retrieve the original "B" matrix ?.  Is it possible ?

Comment: Yes, it is fast if you know size of the original matrix. `s = size(B);[~,f]= find(result);z=zeros(s);z(f)=1;` An iterative method can be used to find size of the original matrix if it is unknown.