# MATLAB: Turn every element of complex matrix into another matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a n x n matrix consisting of complex elements. I want to substitute each element x with a new matrix [Im(x) -Re(x); Re(x) Im(x)]. Is there an easy way of doing this (preferably without using for-loops)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way using [`kron`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/kron.html). It is probably a little wasteful in terms of operations:

```
A = [1+5j, 2+3j, -4j; 2, -2+4j, -3-3j]; % example input
result = real(kron(A, [-1j -1; 1 -1j]));
```

This example gives

```
A =
   1.0000 + 5.0000i   2.0000 + 3.0000i   0.0000 - 4.0000i
   2.0000 + 0.0000i  -2.0000 + 4.0000i  -3.0000 - 3.0000i
result =
     5    -1     3    -2    -4     0
     1     5     2     3     0    -4
     0    -2     4     2    -3     3
     2     0    -2     4    -3    -3
```

---

The following approach is clunkier, but perhaps more efficient:

```
A = [1+5j, 2+3j, -4j; 2, -2+4j, -3-3j]; % example input
result = NaN(size(A)*2); % preallocate
result(1:2:end, 1:2:end) = imag(A);
result(1:2:end, 2:2:end) = -real(A);
result(2:2:end, 1:2:end) = real(A);
result(2:2:end, 2:2:end) = imag(A);
```

Like before, this gives

```
A =
   1.0000 + 5.0000i   2.0000 + 3.0000i   0.0000 - 4.0000i
   2.0000 + 0.0000i  -2.0000 + 4.0000i  -3.0000 - 3.0000i
result =
     5    -1     3    -2    -4     0
     1     5     2     3     0    -4
     0    -2     4     2    -3     3
     2     0    -2     4    -3    -3
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use a series of `reshape` to take advantage of its speed.

First, let's compose the new elements by recognizing that your desired final product involves interleaving the real part and imaginary part -- twice.

```matlab
AA=reshape(A,1,numel(A));
R=real(AA);
I=imag(AA);
new=[reshape([I;-R], [], numel(AA)*2);reshape([R;I], [], numel(AA)*2)];
```

Here, I interleaved the components along the column. Interleaving along column has the pattern of `reshape([...;...],[],numel(...)+numel(...))`.

In `new`, you can see the result of interleaving in producing the desired 2-by-2 blocks. But at this point, the matrix is not arranged in the way desired. To reshape block-wise, we use Divakar's answer such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26917451/3181104), and use it twice: once to reshape for the 2-by-2 blocks, another time to reshape for the correct number of rows in the final matrix.

```matlab
ncols=2; % 2 because the blocks are 2-by-2
nrows=size(A,1)*2;
new=reshape(permute(reshape(new,size(new,1),ncols,[]),[1,3,2]),[],ncols);
new=reshape(permute(reshape(new',size(new,2),nrows,[]),[1,3,2]),[],nrows)';
```

And `new` will have the desired shape.

Example:

```matlab
>> A=rand(2,3)+rand(2,3)*1i
A =
   0.8147 + 0.2785i   0.1270 + 0.9575i   0.6324 + 0.1576i
   0.9058 + 0.5469i   0.9134 + 0.9649i   0.0975 + 0.9706i
>> AA=reshape(A,1,numel(A));
>> I=imag(AA);
>> R=real(AA);
>> new=[reshape([I;-R], [], numel(AA)*2);reshape([R;I], [], numel(AA)*2)];
>> ncols=2;
nrows=size(A,1)*2;
new=reshape(permute(reshape(new,size(new,1),ncols,[]),[1,3,2]),[],ncols);
new=reshape(permute(reshape(new',size(new,2),nrows,[]),[1,3,2]),[],nrows)',
new =
    0.2785   -0.8147    0.9575   -0.1270    0.1576   -0.6324
    0.8147    0.2785    0.1270    0.9575    0.6324    0.1576
    0.5469   -0.9058    0.9649   -0.9134    0.9706   -0.0975
    0.9058    0.5469    0.9134    0.9649    0.0975    0.9706
```

The `reshape` and `permute` calls are designed to be fast in Matlab. While we cannot say with certainty what they do under the hood, they likely do not change the underlying data but change how indices from users convert to addresses for the underlying data. Instantiating this simple formula should cost next to nothing.

Whether this method is truly the most efficient should depend on how you access the final matrix `new`. If you access it column-wise, for example, then it should be equivalent as accessing `AA` as a vector with a stride of 2, in which case the implementation and hardware likely speed it up to as fast as column-wise access of a regular matrix. Your mileage with other access patterns may vary.

Comment: I like this approach, but `permute` is not fast like `reshape` is, because `permute` has to move the elements around

Comment: @LuisMendo: I see. Why/where does permute move elements? It just says shifting dimensions. But dimension affects indexing, not the elements right?

Comment: The reason is that `permute` changes the order of the elements in memory. If you have `A = [10 30 50; 20 40 60];` the order of the elements in memory is what you get with Matlab's linear indexing, `A(:)`, that is, `[10; 20; 30; 40; 50; 60]`. For `B = reshape(A, [3 2]);` the order is the same: `B(:)` is `[10; 20; 30; 40; 50; 60]`. For `C = permute(A, [2 1]);` it changes: `C(:)` is now `[10; 30; 50; 20; 40; 60];`. So the internal representation of the data has to change, unlike with `reshape`.

Comment: More information [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/426295-what-is-the-complexity-of-the-permute-fonction-for-multiway-arrays#answer_343630) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36065182/2586922)

Comment: @LuisMendo: I see. Thank you for the explanation and links! It does make sense that when the flattened representation changes, it is usually better to reconstruct the array than to map the new indices to old with a function. I'll come back to edit my answer later.

Answer (score -2):

Let `A` be the input comple matrix.

Then

```
B=imag(A)-real(A) +1j*(real(A)+imag(A))
```

Then `B` is the sought matrix.

No `for` loops needed, not a single one.

I have assumed that in the question you omitted the '+' or whatever operation combining the 2nd pair.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the OP wants each element replaced by a 2×2 matrix