# Finding same value in rows & columns of a 2D array

Tags: arrays, matlab, sudoku

Hi guys I want to solve sodoku puzzles in matlab. My problem is that I should find same value in every row and every column and every 3*3 sub array.

Our 2d array is 9*9 and populated with value 1-9 randomly.

I wrote this  for finding same value in rows, but I don't know how I should do it for columns and 3*3 sub arrays.

```
conflict_row = 0;

for i=1:9
    temp = 0;
    for j=1:9
       if (temp==A(i,j))
           conflict_row = conflict_row+1;
       end
       temp = A(i,j);
    end
end
```

Sorry I'm a  newbie.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Find values that are present in all columns:

   ```
   v = find(all(any(bsxfun(@eq, A, permute(1:size(A,1), [3 1 2])),1),2));
   ```
2. Find values that are present in all rows:

   ```
   v = find(all(any(bsxfun(@eq, A, permute(1:size(A,2), [3 1 2])),2),1));
   ```
3. Find values that are present in all 3x3 blocks: reshape the matrix as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20337173/2586922) by A. Donda to transform each block into a 3D-slice; then reshape each block into a column; and apply 1:

   ```
   m = 3; %// columns per block
   n = 3; %// rows per block
   B = permute(reshape(permute(reshape(A, size(A, 1), n, []), [2 1 3]), n, m, []), [2 1 3]);
   B = reshape(B,m*n,[]);
   v = find(all(any(bsxfun(@eq, B, permute(1:size(B,1), [3 1 2])),1),2));
   ```

Comment: What can I say...? Awesome... +1

Comment: Thanks! It's always prettier without loops :-)

Comment: @kkuilla It takes times, but trust me, it's worth it! :)

Comment: I absolutely agree. Avoid for loops like the plague although vectorisation can be difficult to understand in the beginning.

Comment: @kkuilla In recent Matlab versions, loops are not as slow as they used to be. But still I like to avoid them

Comment: @LuisMendo I agree. It cleaner and still more efficient I think without them.

Comment: @meysammotamedi Try to see intermediate results step by step, from `permute(1:size(A,1), [3 1 2])`outwards . The third part (based on A. Donda's answer) is also hard to understand for me :-)

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the fastest solution but why don't you make a function of it and use it once for rows and once for columns

```
[conflict_row ] = get_conflict(A)
    for i=1:9
        temp = 0;
        for j=1:9
           if (temp==A(i,j))
               conflict_row = conflict_row+1;
           end
           temp = A(i,j);
        end
    end
```

And then you call it twice

```
conflict_row = get_conflict(A);  % Rows
```

Transpose A to get the columns

Convert the columns to rows and use the same code as before

```
 conflict_col = get_conflict(A.');
```

Comment: above code give number of same values in every Row of the matrix but i dont think it should be the same for every column!? am i right?

Comment: Otherwise, @LuisMendo's answer is probably the most efficient one. He normally has one of the most short and efficient answers.:-)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to work within the same column then you should do something like this (also sorry this is in C# I don't know what language you are working in):

```
int currentCol = 0;

foreach (var item in myMultiArray)
{
    int currentColValue = item[currentCol];
}
```

This works because `myArray` is a array of arrays thus to select a specific column can easily be picked out by just allowing the `foreach` to perform your row iteration, and you just have to select the column you need with the `currentCol` value.

Comment: this is MATLAB; see the tags :)

Comment: Sorry about that, but it should still provide the solution you are looking for.