# Extract and then sum sub-matrices in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Let A=magic(16). Suppose I want to divide A into 2-by-2 sub-matrices and then sum them all into a 2-by-2 matrix. What should I do?

I started with

```
    A=magic(16);
    dim=2*ones(8,1);
    B=mat2cell(A,dim,dim);
```

Comment: Use the first part of [this great answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20337173/2586922) and then `sum(T, 3)`

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks. It is a cute solution. Problem solved.

Comment: Glad it worked :-) I'm closing this as a duplicate then, so that the question doesn't appear as unanswered