# using Mean Square Error to create an index matrix matlab

Tags: matlab

The `Mean Square Error`(MSE), is a method used to define the difference in between two blocks, and can be calculated as follow:
`a` and `b` two blocks equal size

```
MSE = sqrt(sum(sum((a-b).^2)))/size(a or b)
```

If the `MSE` is less than a given threshold, than the two blocks are not diffrent.

Given two matrix `A` and `B`, the purpose is to divide the two matrix to blocks of a given size, then extract the first block from A and let it be `a`, then search for a block `b` from `B` where the `Mean Square Error` between `a` and `b` is less then a given threshold, then return the position of the block `b` from the matrix `B`. and so on. and here is an example:

Given two matrix `A` and `B` where:

```
A= [1 1   4 4   2 2 
    1 1   4 4   2 2

    2 2   9 9   5 5
    2 2   9 9   5 5

    3 3   4 4   9 9
    3 3   4 4   9 9];

B = [ 2 2   4 4   9 9
      2 2   4 4   9 9];
```

the threshold is 2

The first block `a` obtained from the matrix `A`  is:

```
1 1
1 1
```

The block `b` obtained from the matrix `B`  that MSR between `a` and `b` is less than the threshold is:

```
2 2
2 2
```

Therefore we return the position of the block `b` in the matrix `B` which is 1

The second block `a` obtained from the matrix `A`  is:

```
4 4
4 4
```

The block `b` obtained from the matrix `B` where MSR between `a` and `b` is less than threshold is:

```
4 4
4 4
```

Therefore we return the position of the block `b` in the matrix `B` which is 2. and so on.

The final result should be as follow

```
RES= [1 2 1
      1 3 2
      1 2 3];
```

Is there a faster way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a vectorized approach with [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html).

First define data:

```
A = [1 1   4 4   2 2 
     1 1   4 4   2 2
     2 2   9 9   5 5
     2 2   9 9   5 5
     3 3   4 4   9 9
     3 3   4 4   9 9];  %// data: A
B = [2 2   4 4   9 9
     2 2   4 4   9 9];  %// data: B
m = 2;                  %// number of rows per block
n = 2;                  %// number of cols per block
```

Then apply the following steps:

1. Reshape matrices so that each block is a row (inspired by [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20336288/for-loop-to-split-matrix-to-equal-sized-sub-matrices)).
2. Compute the MSE for all pairs of blocks.
3. Find the argmin of the MSE with respect to blocks of `B` (for each block of `A`). Note that if there are several minimizing blocks in `B`  this finds the first.
4. Reshape result into a matrix.

Code:

```
A2 = reshape(permute(reshape(A, size(A, 1), n, []), [2 1 3]), n*m, []);  %// step 1
B2 = reshape(permute(reshape(B, size(B, 1), n, []), [2 1 3]), n*m, []);
mse = squeeze(sum(bsxfun(@minus, A2, permute(B2,[1 3 2])).^2, 1));       %// step 2
[~, result] = min(mse, [], 2);                                           %// step 3
result = reshape(result, size(A,1)/m, size(A,2)/n);                      %// step 4
```