# dividing a matrix into 10 submatrices

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix [x y] of size [86 86]. I want to divide this matrix into 10 sub matrix. For thr last matrix there will be shortage of coordinates but can be padded with zeros.

```
[x y] = size(I)
nSub = 10;
B = mat2cell(I, 2*ones(size(I,1)/2,1), 2*ones(size(I,2)/2,1))
```

I tried using mat2cell function but the output didn't come well.
   Can any one tell me where am going wrong or can I change this function

Comment: Pad the matrix with zeros and apply [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20337173/2586922). Let me know if it works so I can mark this as duplicate

Comment: 10 matrices or 10by10 submatrices?

Answer (score 2):

Does this work for you?

```
I = rand(86,86);
[x y] = size(I)
nSub = 10;

%// padding
xp = x + nSub - mod(x,nSub);
yp = y + nSub - mod(y,nSub);
I(xp,yp) = 0;

%// submatrices
B = mat2cell(I, nSub*ones(xp/nSub,1),nSub*ones(yp/nSub,1))
```

[image]