# Dividing a matrix into sub matrices with same number of rows but different number of columns

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

If, for example, I have a **5000x30 matrix** and I want to obtain **10 sub matrices** having dimensions of **5000x3**, how do I code this in **Matlab**. I have read several post on this issue,[this one here for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20336288/for-loop-to-split-matrix-to-equal-sized-sub-matrices/20337173#20337173),  but none of them keep the number of rows in the submatrices the same as the main matrix.

As I will be handling very large matrices, I would prefer a code that is faster, like using Matlab's inbuilt functions such as `mat2cell` or any other `vectorized` method, but not with loops.

Comment: 5000 by 30 isn't very big. What's wrong with just using `A(:,1:3)` or `A(:,22:25)` when you need to use parts of a matrix? Your question isn't very clear about what sort of results you want, and how you want to use the resulting matrices.

Comment: @David Like I said I will be handling very large matrices, like 500000x300 or higher. `A(:,1:3)` will give me only one sub-matrix. What I want is 10 sub-matrix each having equal dimensions as mentioned above. Each sub-matrix corresponds to a physical behavior and I will using them for further calculations.

Comment: How about `reshape(A, 5000, 3, 10)`?

Comment: @beaker that seems to work pretty well and fast as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As per @beaker comment, using `reshape(A, 5000, 3, 10)` solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
A = rand(5000,30);
b = {}; % Somewhere to store sub-matrices
for k = 1:10
    b{k} = A(:, (k*3-2):(k*3));
end
```

Comment: Sorry, but I would like not to use loops. Hence, the preference for a `vectorized` method.