# Matlab - Matrix separate into submatrices

Tags: matlab, matrix, split

I have a homework in which i have 640x480 image and i want to divide it to 16x16 blocks. 
Can someone tell me how to do it? If possible i would like to avoid loops. 
I've been trying for hours to do it, but no luck...

Comment: Oh ok, so I assume you actually wanted somebody to give you the code to do it, as Ben A did, without even having think about it... not a good way to start here.

Comment: Next time be sure to include the code you tried. Even if it does not work. We need to *see* the code to help diagnose the problem.  Also, posting it demonstrates that you have put some effort into it and are not just asking someone to do your homework for you. (Since that completely defeats the purpose of homework, posts like that tend to get down voted .. a lot.)

Comment: similar/related questions: [Is there a substitute for blockproc in Matlab?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11238828/97160), [Matlab - merge submatrices](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6283918/97160), [How to divide an image into blocks in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1637000/97160)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This likely isn't best practice, but something you can do if you want.  It will allow you to call each 16x16 block from the resulting 2-D matrix that will be 40 x 30.

Note: this is just some typed up code, I haven't tested it myself.

If you want to parse it into a cell array you could do something like this:

```
%Original Image
Image = imread(somefilename);

%Block size desired (16x16)
bsize = 16;

% 40 and 30 come from dividing the 640 and 480 by 16 since you want 16x16 blocks.
% result = mat2cell(Y, bsize*ones(1,40), bsize*ones(1,30))
result = mat2cell(Y, bsize*ones(1,size(Image,1)/bsize), bsize*ones(1,size(Image,1)/bsize));
```

Comment: thanks a lot m8 you've been very helpful

Comment: If by helpful you mean "give me the code so I won't have to use my brain".

Answer (score 3):

I think the best for you would be to use the Matlab function [blockproc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/blockproc.html).
Dig into the matlab code if you really want to get the blocks, but I guess you want to apply some processing function to your image? Let's say you want to do some image compression, then call blockproc by giving it as the parameters the compression function and the blocks size.

If you want to get the blocks or don't have the Image Processing toolbox available, please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637000/how-to-divide-an-image-into-blocks-in-matlab), your question has actually been asked many times (did you even bother to search for it??).